# libSpotifySDK : Timeout when loading playlist

Tags: python, spotify, libspotify

I'm using libSpotify 12.1.51 (linux-libc6 x86_64) and pyspotify to make requests to spotify from python.

We have been using this code for a long time, but all of a sudden timeouts have started a couple of weeks ago. Every time I try to load a playlist, I get a timeout (I have tried with many playlists)

Here's some code that replicates the issue:

```
import spotify
import logging
import os

class SpotifyClient(object):
    def __init__(self):
        config = spotify.Config()
        config.load_application_key_file(filename=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'spotify_appkey.key'))
        if spotify.session_instance:
            self.session = spotify.session_instance
        else:
            self.session = spotify.Session(config=config)
        if not self.session.connection_state == spotify.ConnectionState.LOGGED_IN:
            self.session.login('OUR_USERNAME', 'OUR_PASSWORD')
        while not self.session.user:
            self.session.process_events()

    def load_playlist(self, playlist_uri):
       self.playlist = spotify.Link(playlist_uri).as_playlist()
       self.playlist.load(timeout=20)

if __name__ == '__main__':

   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

   client = SpotifyClient()
   client.load_playlist('spotify:user:melek136:playlist:32Gl8vkJmvJCHejGTEgM1t')
```

The playlist was just one I chose at random from the list of ones I am trying.

Here is what gets output to the console:

```
DEBUG:spotify.session:Notify main thread
DEBUG:spotify.session:Log message from Spotify: 16:18:40.516 E [ap:4172] ChannelError(0, 1, playlist)
DEBUG:spotify.session:Notify main thread
DEBUG:spotify.playlist:Playlist state changed
DEBUG:spotify.session:Notify main thread
DEBUG:spotify.session:Notify main thread
DEBUG:spotify.session:Notify main thread
DEBUG:spotify.session:Notify main thread
DEBUG:spotify.session:Notify main thread
DEBUG:spotify.session:Notify main thread
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "x.py", line 27, in <module>
    client.load_playlist('spotify:user:melek136:playlist:32Gl8vkJmvJCHejGTEgM1t')
File "x.py", line 20, in load_playlist
    self.playlist.load(timeout=20)
File "/home/entura/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spotify/playlist.py", line 103, in load
    return utils.load(self, timeout=timeout)
File "/home/entura/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spotify/utils.py", line 222, in load
    raise spotify.Timeout(timeout)
spotify.error.Timeout: Operation did not complete in 20.000s
```

Comment: Could this be related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29059169/libspotify-based-client-slow-but-spotifys-own-client-fast

Answer (score 1):

libspotify itself doesn't have a timeout for loading playlists. Indeed, in a perfect storm of conditions (no local cache, large account, playlist service acting slow) it can take many minutes for playlists to load.

I'm not well versed in the Python bindings for libspotify, but the timeout is certainly introduced there. So, to fix it:

1. Increase the timeout value
2. Remove the timeout entirely (or, I guess, set it some crazy high number)

Sometimes the Spotify playlist service has a bad day and slows right down or goes down altogether. If the application you're making is a user-facing thing, you should just tell the user that the playlist is loading and leave it at the rather than erroring out.

As for the timing, well, it's possible that your cache is broken and it's causing libspotify to need more time to load playlists. Maybe the playlists you were loading were really close to the timeout and now they trigger it. Perhaps your libspotify connections are being load-balanced out to a Spotify server further away from your physical location than before. You can't affect any of these things, apart from deleting your cache.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Where is the cache located on the filesystem (Linux) so that I can delete it? Also - I have tried a timeout of 10000 seconds, it still hits the timeout. (I do get Notify main thread) callbacks for the entire period, but it never returns :(

Comment: The cache is located wherever you tell it to go - it's parameter to libspotify's init method.