# libSpotify-based client slow, but Spotify's own client fast

Tags: libspotify

I've run into some weird issues with libSpotify. It seems that any libSpotify-based client will take ages to process requests (sometimes 20 seconds for a simple search, seconds for loading one single image, etc..) sent to Spotify servers, whereas Spotify's own desktop client for Windows works extremely well on the same system, processing requests and loading images in near realtime.

Even the demo app provided with libSpotify, called spshell, exhibits massive problems:
[image: timeout problems in libSpotify's spshell]

Did anyone experience similar problems and/or knows the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Magically works again since today, no clue why.

Comment: And now it doesn't anymore again.